# IllegalArgumentException when attempting to start jetty server using gradle plugin

Tags: jetty, gradle

I am trying to use the jetty gradle plugin to run a jetty server for functional testing. However, I am getting an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object is not of type class org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext`.

I have followed the example shown [here](https://github.com/jamescarr/gradle-jetty-h2) and can't see what I am doing differently. The relevant part of the build file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'jetty'
dependencies {
    providedRuntime 'com.h2database:h2:1.3.167'
    providedRuntime 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4'
}

jettyRunWar {
  httpPort = 8083
  stopPort = 8085
  stopKey = "stopKey"
  jettyConfig = file("$projectDir/jetty-config/jetty.xml")
}

jettyStop {
  stopPort = 8085
  stopKey = "stopKey"
}
```

And my jetty.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
 <Set name="contextPath">/gateway</Set>
 <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
     <Arg>
     </Arg>
     <Arg>jdbc/gateway</Arg>
     <Arg>
         <New class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
             <Set name="url">jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/build/db; USER=sa</Set>
         </New>
     </Arg>
 </New>
</Configure>
```

The stacktrace can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/bgreen1005/7f92737d26e4ac289e65).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that it's a bug in the Jetty plugin. In general, the Jetty plugin is quite limited and outdated, and I recommend to try the [arquillian-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/aslakknutsen/arquillian-gradle-plugin) instead. This is where Gradle's container support is heading.

Comment: I have added a link to the stacktrace. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Sorry for the really late reply. Just seen that you edited the answer. This was the route we took, so thank you.